# Reuse select new object in linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Below is my linq code and it works. My question is how I can "reuse" those part new ContactResponse, and new AddressResponse in a function to reuse it in another query?

```
var queryset = (
            from a in _repoWrapper.Workshop.FindAll()
            where (a.IsActive == true && a.Entity.EntityType.Code == Global.EntityTypeServiceCenterCode)
            select new ServiceCenterResponse
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                EntityId = a.EntityId,
                Contacts = a.WorkshopContacts.Select(p => new ContactResponse
                {
                    Id = p.Contact.Id,
                    Type = p.Contact.ContactType.Description,
                    Code = p.Contact.ContactType.Code,
                    Value = p.Contact.Value
                }).ToList(),
                Addresses = a.WorkshopAddresses.Select(p => new AddressResponse
                {
                    Id = p.Address.Id,
                    AddressType = p.Address.AddressType.Code,
                    StreetLine1 = p.Address.StreetLine1,
                    StreetLine2 = p.Address.StreetLine2,
                    City = p.Address.City,
                    State = p.Address.State,
                    PostCode = p.Address.PostCode,
                    Country = p.Address.Country,
                    Longitude = p.Address.Longitude,
                    Latitude = p.Address.Latitude,
                    Others = p.Address.Others
                }).ToList()
            }
        );
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of how you would be using those resealable query ?

Comment: create a method, say CreateContactResponse, that accepts a WorkshopContact parameter and returns a ContactResponse object, and use the method like `a.WorkshopContacts.Select(p => CreateContactResponse(p)).ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correct understand your question, then try this:

```
 Func<WorkshopContact, ContactResponse> contactResponseProjection= p => new ContactResponse
 {
   Id = p.Contact.Id,
   Type = p.Contact.ContactType.Description,
   Code = p.Contact.ContactType.Code,
   Value = p.Contact.Value
 };
```

And use:

```
...
  Contacts = a.WorkshopContacts.Select(contactResponseProjection).ToList(),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq has a parameter of type Func in the Select method. This means that you can pass a method to it.
Let me try to do an example.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
list.Select(AddOne);
```

where `AddOne` is a method that you can declare and must have a parameter of type `int` and a return of whatever you'd like to return. eg.

```
public int AddOne(int value)
{
    return value + 1;
}
```